# How to categorize Room's data?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room

I'm writing a simple app for a restaurant(just for practice).there are three categories for Foods(say fast food,salad,and sandwich). I want to show these foods in three different  RecyclerView based on the category that user selected in MainActivity.
My strategy to do this (i think it is not good) is:

1.i have a enum class with three item for each category.

enum class Types {
    FASTFOOD,
    SALAD,
    SANDWICH
}

2. Each Food have a parameter in it's constructor:

class Food(...  , type: Types)

3. get special category from Room db based on it's Type

@Query (SELECT * FROM foods WHERE type=:type)
fun getFastFoods(type:Types): List

Is there a better way to categorize items in Room?
is the getFastFood method efficient for get data from Room?

Answer (score 0):

Just use converter e.g.

```
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class Database : RoomDatabase()
```

```
object Converters {

    @JvmStatic
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromTypes(value: Types): String {
        return value.toString()
    }

    @JvmStatic
    @TypeConverter
    fun toTypes(value: String): Types {
        return Types.valueOf(value)
    }
}
```

Now in db `Types` field is stored as string which is the name property from enum

Comment: Thank you but this  is not my problem. I want to know there is better way to categorize series of items?